# Filter select with NgTable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have two select elements. In my first select, I load names. I want that when I select a name, the second select element's options are filtered to include only the age of the selected user.

Example:

When I select `Jacob` in my first select, I want my `Age` select to have `27` as the only option.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XRX2nI7NE6kWtnU6KnhA?p=preview)

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data" ng-class="{ 'emphasis': user.money > 500 }">
        <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{ 'name': 'select' }" filter-data="names($column)">
            {{user.name}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Age'" filter="{ 'age': 'select' }" filter-data="ages($column)">
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I automatically filter my second select element based on the first select element?

Comment: what do you want to happen after you select something?

Comment: this could be a possible solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221692/smart-table-how-to-reset-filter-collection)

Comment: How can you put a bounty on a question that declares itself to be a duplicate of another question? Why not put the bounty on the original?

Comment: @AustinMullins for more visibility

Comment: @Austin Mullins Someone can delete or close this thread

Comment: That works :) Downvote reversed - it's a good question BTW, hope you get a good answer!

Comment: Didnt get much time.. but something on this line ? http://plnkr.co/edit/Kr24jsovpTdtxSvrjtqM?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3tLixkFKYgpXfx04PbaD?p=preview

One approach is to create custom templates for your filters.  This way you have full control over the arrays that the filters are bound to, and you can easily attach change events:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ng-table/filters/name.html">
  <select ng-options="name.id as name.title for name in nameOptions" 
          ng-model="params.filter()['name']" 
          ng-change="ages(column, params.filter()['name'])">
  </select>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ng-table/filters/age.html">
  <select ng-options="age.id as age.title for age in ageOptions" 
          ng-model="params.filter()['age']"></select>
</script>
```

Then, use the templates in your `ng-table` markup:

```
<td data-title="'Name'" filter="{ 'name': 'name' }" filter-data="names($column)">
  {{user.name}}
</td>
<td data-title="'Age'" filter="{ 'age': 'age' }" filter-data="ages($column)">
  {{user.age}}
</td>
```

You can populate the option arrays in your existing `names` and `ages` functions:

```
$scope.names = function(column) {
    ...

    $scope.nameOptions = names;

    ...
};


$scope.ages = function(column, name) {      
  var def = $q.defer(),
      arr = [],
      ages = [];
  angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
      if (inArray(item.age, arr) === -1) {
          if (angular.isUndefined(name) || item.name === name) {
            arr.push(item.age);
            ages.push({
                'id': item.age,
                'title': item.age
            });
          }
      }
  });

  $scope.ageOptions = ages;

  def.resolve(ages);
  return def;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this. Let me know if it is same what you need. 
DEMO: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjm2mhhL/3/)

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item as item for item in name">
    <option value="">Select Name</option>
</select>
<pre>selectedItem: {{selectedName | json}}</pre>

<select ng-model="selectedage" ng-options="item as item for item in age">
    <option ng-if="!selectedage" value="">Select age</option>
</select>
<pre>selectedItem: {{selectedage | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {

$scope.name = ["Ved", "James", "Doe","Prakash" ];
var age = {Ved :["25"],James :["26"],Doe:["27"],Prakash:["28"]};
    $scope.$watch('selectedName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if ( newValue) {
            var name = $scope.selectedName;
  $scope.age = age[name];
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/5fvtiept6M6VpAmo8a5f?p=preview
So what you can do is,you can use your first select ng-model object which is  as a filter to the second dropdown.

**or**

user first select binded object which is "formData.name" in here in example,
in second dropdown.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.js"></script>

    <link data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
      <tr>
            <td data-title="'Name'">
              <select name="name" 
                data-ng-model="formData.name"
                ng-options="user.name for user in $data" 
                ng-change="changeAge(formData.name)"
                required >
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Age'">
                <select name="age" data-ng-model="formData.age"
                >
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <option value="">{{formData.name.age}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in $data|filter:formData.name">
              <td>
                {{user.name}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{user.age}}
              </td>
            </tr>
    </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok for you're reponse but why in the select `name` there is duplicate entries .?

Comment: okay dats becuz you have same name object  for 3 or 4 i guess.. u can apply filter on them too based on their money property.. le me knoe if u want fiddle for that.. thank you :)

Comment: It’s posible to have a Fiddle please

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/QDU34o9FFnGitiKC8UVm?p=preview   so i have created this plunker which will filter your object array based on the condition in filterData() function and the value you give in Filter by money search box.