# smart-table - how to reset filter collection?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

New to Angular and smart-table..

This smart-table setup works and filters correctly, but trying to reset or clear the filters doesn't re-filter the table. Why not?

Does updating an input with ng-model binding not trigger a watch that smart-table is looking for?

Plunker is available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4os3oWeJtEtMfa89QoQd?p=preview

Code:

```js
        var actionQueue = [
            { Type: 'User Access Request', Description: 'test test test test test test test', DateRequested: '5/5/15' },
            { Type: 'User Access Request', Description: 'blah blah', DateRequested: '3/3/10' },
            { Type: 'Project Approval Request', Description: 'project needs approving', DateRequested: '1/1/08' }
        ];

        $scope.actionQueueCollection = actionQueue;


        $scope.predicates = [{ Name: 'All', Value: '' }, { Name: 'User Access Request', Value: 'User Access Request' }, { Name: 'Project Approval Request', Value: 'Project Approval Request' }];
        $scope.selectedPredicate = $scope.predicates[0];

        $scope.clearFilter = function () {
            $scope.selectedPredicate = $scope.predicates[0];
            $scope.searchFilter = '';

        }
```

Markup:

```html
    <table st-table="actionQueueCollection" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div>
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="filterType">Filter: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select class="form-control input-sm" id="filterType" name="filterType" ng-model="selectedPredicate" ng-options="predicate.Name for predicate in predicates track by predicate.Value" st-search="Type"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th colspan="3">
                    <div class="form-horizontal form-group-sm">
                        <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                            <input st-search placeholder="search" class="form-control input-sm" type="search" ng-model="searchFilter" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="clearFilter()">CLEAR</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Date Requested</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="action in actionQueueCollection">
                <td>{{action.Type}}</td>
                <td>{{action.Description}}</td>
                <td>{{action.DateRequested}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Check this similar approach to yours https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/164

Answer (score 9):

Pretty much the same thing.
Usage is a little easier this way

```
.directive("stResetSearch", function() {
         return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                require: '^stTable',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                  return element.bind('click', function() {
                    return scope.$apply(function() {
                      var tableState;
                      tableState = ctrl.tableState();
                      tableState.search.predicateObject = {};
                      tableState.pagination.start = 0;
                      return ctrl.pipe();
                    });
                  });
                }
              };
    })
```

And then usage is like this

```
<button type="button" st-reset-search>Clear Filters</button>
```

found here:
https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/164

Answer (score 2):

So this is what I've come up with... not sure if its a good approach or not, but from what I gather I need to create a lot of directives to exert functionality over smart-table?

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-default" smart-table-reset="clearFilter()">
```

```js
    .directive('smartTableReset', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^stTable',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                var tableCtrl = ctrl;
                var fn = $parse(attr['smartTableReset']);

                element.on('click', function (event) {
                    ctrl.tableState().search = {};
                    tableCtrl.search('', '');
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        fn(scope, {
                            $event: event
                        })
                    });
                });
            }
        };
```